# jquery remove() does not remove reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, pointers

**strong text**When i create a reference to a DOM object and then remove it the reference is still there.

```
var test = $("#test")
console.log(test.length); //1
$('#test').remove();
console.log(test.html()); //test
console.log( $("#test").html() ) //undefined
```

I think this has to be a new feature/bug of jquery; we recently updated.  Major systemic issue if this is true that was not present prior to update(pretty sure)

EDIT:  The variable is a clone of the element? Its supposed to be a pointer/reference to the element.

EDIT 2:  Does the ability to have a pointer to an DOM object not make sense?  I want to have a variable that points to the DOM object so i can monitor it without having to do a selector on the DOM everytime.

EDIT 3: simplified example of lots of functions altering a globally scoped object

```
GLOBAL_OBJECT ={};

function add_image(itemName =="item1"){
        //fetch item and insert into dom
        $(body).append(largeImage);
        GLOBAL_OBJECT[itemName] = $(largeImageID);
}

function move_me(itemName){
    if(itemName in GLOBAL_OBJECT && GLOBAL_OBJECT[itemName].length){
        GLOBAL_OBJECT[itemName].css(
            "top":aTop,
            "left":aLeft
        )
    }else{
       add_image(itemName);
    }
}
function hideImages(){
    $('canvas.largeImages').remove();
}

add_image();
hideImages();
move_me("item1");
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rt3omad/1/)

[From Manual](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> searches through the DOM for any elements that match the provided
> selector and creates a new jQuery object that references these
> elements

Comment: Your code looks like it's working correctly. You locate the element in the DOM, and that works. You remove it, and then it's no longer in the DOM, which is why you get that `undefined`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is test that is supposed to be a reference to the element still exists. Element gone pointer to element should be gone

Comment: It is gone. That's why `$("#test")` at the end of your code returns an empty jQuery object, and that's why you get `undefined`.

Comment: That's the intended behaviour, remove only removes it from the dom

Comment: This is not new jQuery behavior. It has worked like that for well over a decade, if not forever.

Comment: `var test` is not a pointer.

Comment: Your variable `test` remains the jQuery object that it was at the start of your code. Its contents do not change after `remove()`, however it is no longer part of the DOM, as your last line of code demonstrates. JavaScript does not really have "pointers", so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: so ` new jQuery object that references these elements` is wrong.  It really doesn't reference the DOM object. It really clones it

Comment: No, that is absolutely not correct. Removing a DOM element from the DOM does not destroy the element.

Comment: well then what does remove() do.  Would you not use detach() if you just wanted to remove it from the DOM?

Comment: It **removes** the element from the DOM. [The difference is described in the jQuery documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Comment: how do delete then? where is this element going after remove()?

Comment: What difference does it make? It will be garbage collected eventually.

Comment: The reference `test` keeps the object alive.  It has to exist as long as `test` is in scope.  Once your function ends, it can be garbage collected, since it's no longer referenced.  There is no other way to get rid of it, nor should you particularly care about it.

Comment: cause of demo shown uptop.. Will it be "unrefrenced" from the variable after GC?

Comment: No, because the jQuery object itself is still "live". What **exactly** is the problem you're trying to solve? jQuery is not broken and has not changed in any substantive way for a long time.

Comment: I want to have a pointer to a DOM object.  Is that not possible.  jquery clearly states "references these elements"

Comment: All references to any kind of object in JavaScript are effectively pointers, but that terminology is not appropriate to JavaScript programming. When you create a jQuery object, you get a reference to it, and inside of that object there will be references to other objects including elements in the DOM. Removing an element from the DOM does *not* remove the element itself from existence. The jQuery object retains the reference to the DOM element and it will continue to exist, but it will not be part of the page structure.

Comment: "so i can monitor it without having to do a selector on the DOM everytime" -- so...bind an event to the DOM element and do whatever it is you need to do when the event is triggered.

Comment: so effectively there is no way to delete this element without deleting it in every object that it is referenced in? If multiple object point to element it can only be removed by deleting the reference in each object one by one and never at the source?

Comment: WHY are you wanting to delete `var test` ?  That makes no sense.  You need to provide an example demonstrating WHY you want to do that.  Like, what problem or error are you encountering with `var test` ?

Comment: Again, why do you care? A random DOM element floating around, not being part of the DOM, is just a random DOM element. It will not be found by queries to the DOM because *it's not in the DOM*.

Comment: "random DOM element" are large images moving on a panning plot. The ability to remove and add them when they are in and out of plot range is needed at ~60hz.  So if element is in range we have  canvas elements they need to be sized and moved on a plot that is panning/zooming etc.  Then when out of range removed from dom and re inserted when back in range.

Comment: See answer for what may be a clearer explanation. Nothing has changed with regard to how jQuery does what it does in regards to your question. You have not explained why you feel that something has gone wrong; are there errors? Weird behavior? It's hard to help without knowing about the actual phenomena that led you to post your question.

Comment: If you really need `var test` to no longer hold it's originally assigned object, you can just set `test` to null or undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down.

```
var test = $("#test")
```

This creates a new jQuery object based on a search for an element in the DOM with id "test".

```
console.log(test.length); //1
```

Because the length of the jQuery element is 1, we know that there is in fact such an element.

```
$('#test').remove();
```

This tells jQuery to unlink the element from the DOM. This means that the parent element no longer refers to the previously-located DOM element. However, the element, as an object, still exists.

```
console.log(test.html()); //test
```

This makes sense, because, as I said, the element and all its child nodes still exist, including the text node that apparently contains the text "test". They are not in the DOM, but they have not vanished from our plane of reality. When the jQuery object goes out of scope and is eventually garbage-collected, the DOM element and its children will eventually also be garbage-collected.

```
console.log( $("#test").html() ) //undefined
```

This also makes sense. The element with id "test" was removed from the DOM, so this new attempt to locate it by creating a **new** jQuery object results in a zero-length instance, and therefore `.html()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Going to mark this as an correct, but damn does this seem wrong to me.  You create a reference that now is in control of and takes over what it is referencing.  What  a nightmare if you had 100's of object referencing an element that you needed to delete.  Or multiple functions written by different programmers.  The element can never be 
 truly deleted because some random person created a reference to it.

Comment: Well, welcome to JavaScript, and other languages with managed memory like C# and Java. The runtime manages memory. If you want to control that, you need to be aware of how scope works. A place to start might be to move to using `const` and `let` instead of `var`, because they more tightly restrict variable scope.